# an idiom for "I really love"

Tags: idiom-requests

I am looking for an interesting idiom but with also a poetic slant to it. Something which means the same as "I *really* love something".

For instance, an idiom that can be used instead of the bold part and would have a similar meaning to:

> **I love** this song **madly**.

Does such an idiom exist in English?

Comment: How can anyone answer what is "interesting" to you? There are an unlimited number of ways of saying this and we don't know what you will like. This question can't be answered objectively.

Comment: I wonder why the suspiciously duplicate-looking ['What is an expression for something you particularly like?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33020/what-is-an-expression-for-something-you-particularly-like/33057#33057) wasn't closed?

Answer (score 2):

This is not an idiom per se, but I'd say:

> I **really dig** something.

The verb 'dig' is defined in [this learner's dictionary](https://learnersdictionary.com/definition/dig) as:

> 4 *slang*
>
> **a** [+ object] : to like or admire (someone or something)
>
> - I really *dig* this music.

Answer (score 1):

*This song **bowls me over***, perhaps?

[***Bowl over***](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/bowl-over) - to surprise someone by being very beautiful, impressive, unexpected etc